# when uploading file in codeigniter why showing Website is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, codeigniter, cpanel

I have a project on codeigniter that worked well on localhost now when I uploaded in cpanel and go to upload a file to my site its showing *example.com* is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500
why? Can anyone tell me what to do?

```
public function doupload($id,$action)
{

    $config['upload_path']          = 'SliderImages/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|psd|pdf|tiff';
    $config['overwrite']            = TRUE;
    $config['encrypt_name']         = false;
    $config['max_size']             = 10000000;
    $config['max_width']            = 999999;
    $config['max_height']           =99999;

    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    $files = $_FILES;

    if($action == "insert")
    {


            if($_FILES['slide_image']['name'] !== '')
            {

                    $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $files['slide_image']['name'];
                    $file_name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
                    $name =explode('.',$file_name);
                    $_FILES['userfile']['name'] = $id. '.' .$name[1];
                    $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $files['slide_image']['type'];
                    $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $files['slide_image']['tmp_name'];
                    $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $files['slide_image']['error'];
                    $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $files['slide_image']['size']; 

                    //$this->upload->do_upload();
                    if (!$this->upload->do_upload())
                    {                               
                        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());         
                        return  $error; 
                        //print_r($error);die();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $msg = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());               
                        return $this->upload->data('file_name');

                    }

            }

    }


}
```

Comment: Well, try to check the server log, or at least activate the php display errors to have more details about your problem

Comment: Please check the PHP Version of the your server is that compatible with your code.. as we have latest version 7.0

Comment: if it is set to the latest then try to set it to 5.6 PHP version

Comment: What is the permission of index.php and also other files? 755 perhaps?

Comment: yes file and folder permission also

Answer (score 2):

check on system/libraries/upload.php
.
.
find "protected function _file_mime_type"
.
.
change code from

```
$finfo = @finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);
        if (is_resource($finfo)) // It is possible that a FALSE value is returned, if there is no magic MIME database file found on the system
        {
            $mime = @finfo_file($finfo, $file['tmp_name']);
            finfo_close($finfo);

            /* According to the comments section of the PHP manual page,
             * it is possible that this function returns an empty string
             * for some files (e.g. if they don't exist in the magic MIME database)
             */
            if (is_string($mime) && preg_match($regexp, $mime, $matches))
            {
                $this->file_type = $matches[1];
                return;
            }
        }
```

.
.
to
.
.

```
if (function_exists('finfo_file'))
        {

            $finfo = @finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);            
            if (is_resource($finfo)) // It is possible that a FALSE value is returned, if there is no magic MIME database file found on the system
            {
                $mime = @finfo_file($finfo, $file['tmp_name']);
                finfo_close($finfo);

                /* According to the comments section of the PHP manual page,
                 * it is possible that this function returns an empty string
                 * for some files (e.g. if they don't exist in the magic MIME database)
                 */
                if (is_string($mime) && preg_match($regexp, $mime, $matches))
                {
                    $this->file_type = $matches[1];
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

.
.
i solved it on my error, hope this work for u too, cmiiw